# JMS Messaging in Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

Is JMS not a preferred way of messaging mechanism for microservices deployed in cloud foundry? If so , please can you elaborate on why it isn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer: Cloud Foundry has no opinions on how your applications communicate.

There are a bunch of reasons you may wish to use RESTful point-to-point communication rather than using message brokers. One of the things worth considering is that the apps you run on Cloud Foundry will be ephemeral, and may be terminated and recreated at any point.

Messaging queue technologies tend to be used in a way that people make assumptions about things like "exactly once" semantics, which are physically impossible to guarantee in a distributed environment. Distributed transactions become more tricky in a distributed environment too, and because there are more network hops there is more uncertainty in the system and an increased likelihood of seeing failure.

There's lots more that could be said on the matter, but you don't often see things like JMS being discussed with Cloud Native apps because those technologies are often associated with design patterns that aren't cloud-friendly, even if there is nothing that intrinsically makes them so.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerBetter. I do however see rabbitmq built into PCF market place and also have seen apps deployed in CF use Kafka. Isn't what you mentioned applicable for these as well ? Is there any advantage of moving away from JMS to AMQP for cloud native apps ?

Comment: Pivotal do offer RabbitMQ (I worked on that offering for a short while) and using Kafka for ingestion is a common pattern. Using Kafka for inter-microservice communication is something that I don't see very often though, and one could argue that the RabbitMQ support is there because people asked for it, not because it's a great idea for microservices universally though.

It's a broad topic. Personally I like the temporal decoupling of message brokers, and I think _most_ people can get away with them rather than a complicated arrangement of Netflix implementations.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerBetter !